# Macro to capitalize all letters and change breaks to underlines

Tags: underline, stringstrings

I'm trying to make a macro that will take an input phrase, capitalize all letters, and replace all breaks with underlines:

```
\ctest{one word} => ONE_WORD
```

I've been trying to use the `stringstrings` package for this:

```
\newcommand{\ctest}[1]{%
\solelyuppercase[e]{#1}%
\getargs{\thestring}%
{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont \argi\underline{{ }}\argii}}
```

I'm happy with the result, but I need the macro to be flexible in accepting phrases with one, two, three, or four words. I can use `\narg` to get the word count, but I have no idea how to call `\argi`, `\argii`, ... flexibly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to save the result, or merely output it?

Comment: You should just use VIM. ;)

Answer (score 6):

With `expl3`, with support for accented characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % just for testing strange chars

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ctest}{m}
 {
  % set the token list to the upper case version of the inptu
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \text_uppercase:n { #1 } }
  % replace spaces with underscores
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { \c_underscore_str }
  % produce the text
  \texttt{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ctest{one word}

\ctest{élite über Straße l'Hôpital}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could someone use `\char_set_uccode:nn` to have the white spaces replaced by `\c_underscore_str`?

Comment: @Skillmon Not really: TeX normalizes tokens with category code 10 to spaces. You can only set the `\uccode` to another character, not to a macro.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' env. and '\luastring' macro
%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function ctest ( s )
   tex.sprint (string.upper ( string.gsub ( s , "%s" , "\\_" ) ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% LaTeX-side code
\newcommand\ctest[1]{\directlua{ctest(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\ctest{one word}

\ctest{several no longer separate words}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the argument of `\ctest` may contain unicode-encoded characters, simply switch the line

```
   tex.sprint ( string.upper ( string.gsub ( "%s" , "\\_" ) ) )
```

in the Lua function to

```
   tex.sprint ( unicode.utf8.upper ( unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "%s","\\_" ) ) )
```

i.e., replace `string.upper` with `unicode.utf8.upper` and `string.gsub` with `unicode.utf8.gsub`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?  `T1` encoding (or rather, not `OT1`) is essential here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand\ctest[1]{%
  \convertchar[e]{#1}{ }{\_}%
  \caseupper[v]{\thestring}
}
\begin{document}
\ctest{one word} $a_b$
\ctest{one two three words}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also available in `\thestring`.

---

This might be a better way, using the `listofitems` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\ctest[1]{%
  \setsepchar{ }%
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\i\in\mylist{\ifnum\icnt=1\else\textunderscore\fi%
  \expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\i}}%
}
\begin{document}
\ctest{one word}
\ctest{one two three words}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One quick follow up: if I'm understanding the stringstrings documentation correctly, I'm surprised that \convertchar can accept a null string in the from string argument. Did I just understand that incorrectly?  Thanks again for all of the help!!!

Comment: @MoneerHelu It is not a null string, but rather a blank space between the braces.